# LDAP and QueryDsl

Tags: spring, ldap, querydsl

I need to use a pageable search from LDAP server. 
There are QueryDslLdapRepository class, but I haven't found an example to use this class.  
Is there any one have used this class ? 
can I use other solution to get a pageable list of user from LDAP ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Spring LDAP?

http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#paged-search-results